# For all sets A, B, and C, does the equality hold

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

For all sets A, B, and C, does the following equality hold?

> $A-(B-C) = (A-B) - C$

$A\cap (\bar B\cup  C) = (\bar B \cap A) \cap C$  by DeMorgan's

From this, I am able to obtain

$A=$ on the left side by Absorption, but I am stuck on the right side.

Any advice here?

Comment: Suppose $a$ is a member of $A,B$ and $C$. Then it is not a member of $B\setminus C$, so it is a member of $A\setminus(B\setminus C)$. But it is not a member of $X\setminus C$ for any $X$.

Comment: So, using that logic, this equality would not hold? @almagest

Comment: What do you think? The question was whether the equality holds for *all* sets $A,B,C$.

Comment: Since $a$ is not in $C$, then it does not hold. @almagest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another counter-example: suppose $C\subset B$. Then 
$$A-(B-C)=(A-B)\cup(A\cap C)\quad\text{while}\quad (A-B)-C=A-B.$$
Actually, in the general case, $(A-B)-C=A-(B\cup C)$.

Comment: Using this counterexample, we would have $(A-B) ≠ (A-B) \cup (A\cap C)$, meaning the equality does not hold?

Comment: Yes, unless $A$ and $C$ are disjoint.

Answer (score 0):

$A=\{a,b,c,d\}$, $B=\{a,c\}$ and $C=\{c,d\}$. Try it!

Intuition: On the left side you first 'shrink' a set ($B-C$), then substract it from $A$. On the right side you do $A-B$, then from what is left you take $C$.